# How to recognize very short time difference?

Tags: c#, timer

I am working on application that is testing human reaction time and I want it to be able to count the difference between reaction of one person and reaction of the other person. I tried to use timers but those standard timers in C# are not very effective and not really accurate, they can't count ~1ms difference, not even 5ms difference is accurate enough. Is there any way I could recognize the difference quite exactly? I could not really find something but I think that I could maybe take time of first reaction and then time of second reaction and get the difference but I did not manage to get exact time, is there any way to do that or should I use multimedia timer instead?
(I am looking for simple solution..)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class. `Stopwatch` will provide you with elapsed milliseconds, an elapsed `TimeSpan`, or elapsed ticks (each tick represents 100ns).

Comment: +1, but: *"`Stopwatch` is accurate to 100ns."* Not necessarily, from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx): *"...If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation."* It's *precise* to 100ns, but possibly not that *accurate*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for that clarification. I went off to find a source, and remembered that actually, it's ticks that are 100ns, but the accuracy can vary. Updated.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It declared to be accurate up to 100ns. Check the real frequency by `Frequency` property

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: No, again, it's *precise* to 100ns. The *accuracy* may well be much worse than that, depending on the OS. The docs make a point of this, including an example showing what the real accuracy in a given situation is.

Comment: @ChrisMantle Thanks for answer, 1ms accuracy is really enough, even 2ms would be okay.